# Show $5n^3+7n^5 \equiv 0$ mod 12 for all integers $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

I've been stuck on this question for quite a while now. I could obvious show this by setting $n$ to all numbers from 0-11, however this is not very efficient.

Note $5n^3+7n^5 = n^3(5+7n^2)$. We could use the Chinese remainder theorem, we show $n^3(5+7n^2) \equiv 0 $ mod 3 and mod 4, but this doesn't seem to be any easier. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your way is the best way, just do the mod 3 and the mod 4 cases and you're done!

Comment: $3$ and $4$ separately are just seven cases to check instead of twelve. The cases you skip are also all the hard ones to calculate. That aside, how did $7n^2$ become $17n^2$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, fixed it now :) So I just have to check n=1,2,3,4 holds for this equation, is that correct? e.g. $1^3(5+7\cdot 1^2) = 12 \equiv 0$ mod 3.

Comment: Yup. No need to calculate $5\cdot 7^3$, for instance, so you get away with all the simple arithmetic. I also advise you to check $0$ rather than $4$ (and instead of $3$ when doing mod $3$).

Answer (score 3):

$5 \equiv -7 \pmod{12}\,$, so $\,5n^3+7n^5\equiv 7n^3(n^2-1)\equiv 7n^3(n-1)(n+1) \pmod{12}\,$.

All that's left to note is that:

- the product of $\,3\,$ consecutive integers $\,(n-1)\,n\,(n+1)\,$ is always a multiple of $\,3\,$, since one of them must be a multiple of $\,3\,$ itself;
- $\,n^2(n-1)(n+1)\,$ is a multiple of $\,4\,$, since either $\,n\,$ is even (in which case $\,n^2\,$ is a multiple of $\,4\,$), or $\,n\,$ is odd (in which case $\,n-1\,$ and $\,n+1\,$ are even, so their product is a multiple of $\,4\,$).

Comment: I thought I had not posted that comment, now I have deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with Fermat's/Euler's theorem, then
\begin{align*}
5n^3+7n^5 & \equiv 2n^3+n^5 \pmod{3}\\
& \equiv 2n+n \pmod{3} && \text{using Fermat's theorem}\\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{3}
\end{align*}

Likewise use Euler with mod $4$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with them. Could you give me a link or explanation so I might learn about them?

Comment: @user476255 check this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem out.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now, but how would you use Euler's theorem? All I got was $\phi(3) = 2, \phi(5) = 4$, so we may deduce $n^4 \equiv 1$ mod 4, and I don't see how it's relevant. Am I going completely in the wrong direction?

Comment: @user476255 You don't need $\phi(5)$, but you need $\phi(4)$

Comment: Not $\phi 5$.   $\phi 4 = 2$.  Is if $\gcd(n,4) = 1$ then $5n^3 + 7n^5\equiv n^3 - n^5  \equiv n-n \equiv 0 \mod 4$.  If $\gcd(n,4) \ne 1$ then $2|n$ and $4|5n^3 + 7n^5$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$7n^5+5n^3=7(n^5-5n^3+4n)+40(n^3-n)+12n=$$
$$=7\underbrace{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}_{3q \space and \space 4q'=12q''}+\underbrace{40(n-1)n(n+1)+12n}_{3q *40=12q'}.$$

Comment: :+100 I wish...very nice idea

Comment: @Khosrotash Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, geez.....  $7+5 = 12$ so $5n^3 + 7n^5 \equiv 5n^3 - 5n^5 \equiv -7n^3 + 7n^5$.

Suffices to show $12|n^5 - n^3 = n^3(n^2 - 1)= n^3(n+1)(n-1)$.

.....

$n-1, n, n+1$ are three consecutive integers so $3$ divides one of them.

$n-1,n,n+1$ are two consecutive integers so either $2|n$ in which case $8|n^3$, or $2|n-1$ and $2|n+1$ in which case $4|(n-1)(n+1)$.  In either case $4|n^3(n+1)(n-1)$.

So $12|n^3(n+1)(n-1)$  so

$n^3(n+1)(n-1) \equiv 0 \mod 12$

$n^5 - n^3 \equiv 0 \mod 12$

$7n^5 - 7n^3 \equiv 0 \mod 12$

$7n^5 + 5n^3 \equiv 0 \mod 12$.

Comment: `Even stronger 7n^5 + 5n^3 ≡ 0 mod 24` No, not even for $\,n=1\,$. That's precisely why I avoided the $\,8 \mid n^3(n+1)(n-1)\,$ miscue in my answer, and toned it down to $\,4 \mid n^2(n+1)(n-1)\,$.

Comment: D'oh.  $7 \not\equiv -5 \mod 24$  So even though $24|n^5 - n^3$  In doesn't follow $24|7n^5 + 5n^3$ unless $24|12n^3$ which it only does if $n$ is even  D'oh

Answer (score 0):

The only quadratic residue mod $3$ is $1$.
The only quadratic residue mod $4$ is also $1$.
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
n^3 &\equiv n^5 \pmod{3} &\qquad n^3 &\equiv n^5 \pmod{4}
\end{align*}
and so
$$ n^3 \equiv n^5 \pmod{12} $$
Applying this to the original equation:
$$ 5n^3 + 7n^5 \equiv 12n^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{12} $$

Comment: Well... certainly 0 is also a quadratic residue.